# How to install brew using a shallow clone (especially useful in CI systems)

Tags: bash, git, continuous-integration, homebrew, shallow-clone

The brew installer does a git clone of some very large repositories, which is slow.

It doesn't use:

- shallow clones because GitHub asked them not to so-as to avoid `brew update` being slower c.f. https://github.com/Homebrew/install/issues/541, and
- partial clones are not supported yet c.f. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/13188

In a CI environment where `brew update` is not needed, how can the brew installer be forced to use a shallow clone to speed up the operation?

Answer (score 1):

The installer can be hacked to use shallow clone.  Then an error occurs when the installer tries to run `brew update`.  So the steps are fetch the installer script, force using shallow clone, and remove the use of `brew update`.

```
wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh
sed -i 's:"git" "fetch":"git" "fetch" "--depth" "1":' ./install.sh
sed -i '/"update" "--force"/d' ./install.sh
```

When doing this, be sure to use `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1` and do not use `brew update`.

To do the install, run

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 bash ./install.sh
```

Comment: Aside: having brew using a shallow clone of depth n>1 (2 or more) by default might also help, and not require this sort of thing. GitHub might still object as I think they have special optimization hacks for "first full clone" though.